# macro creates graph but doesn't display until manually select data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in excel that creates a graph from the data is the first worksheet. The issue is that the graph is blank until i right click, select data, press ok. I don't have to actually select the data the values are already populated. Once I do this the graph looks fine. How do I get the graph to show the values without having to manually do this?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = Sheets(1).Range("C1")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(1).Range("AB:AB")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets(1).Range("C:C")
```

Comment: works fine for me... exactly as it is... maybe there's just a lot of data... try to set a `ActiveChart.Refresh` as last step... maybe that helps

Comment: Thanks for the feedback refresh didn't seem to help but if i a create a new sheet first within the macro the data displays fine. Very strange must be something unique to my system. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the Modules in Excel can get corrupted and the code does strange things.

Copy your code into notepad or notepad++, delete the module, add a new module, and paste the code back into the module from notepad.  see if that helps.  I've had to do that more than once.